# SSIS vs Restful Webserviceq

Tags: c#, sql-server, oracle, rest

I have a Oracle DB and have been getting data from it to my SQL Server DB via SSIS packages. Essentially i refresh most of my tables data using SSIS every 5 mins.

I also have a RESTful web service running on my IIS web server which my UI consumes.

I am thinking of either integrating the SSIS into my RESTful web services or removing the SSIS and hitting the Oracle db directly from WS to enhance security and simplify the overall architecture of the system

Would i expect to see a large impact to the speed. Is this essentially a bad idea all together or is it the correct thing to do security wise?

Comment: I am looking at something similar.  I have a WCF service which calls to Salesforce, and to get a full list of all items is pretty slow.  I am going to look to modify my WCF service so that if the data is more than 10 minutes old (for example) execute the SSIS package then return my results from an intermediate table.  So far i have planned but not executed.  Seems like you could adopt something similar?

Comment: @DomCotton thx for suggestion. I would need to research more the WCF stuff. Why did you do WCF?

Comment: I chose WCF because it best fit my required solution.  That part doesn't really matter for you, i suspect if you had a combination of a RESTful service with a simple cache mechanism, and then a call to SSIS when this expires would give you good performance - its only theory for me right now because i haven't implemented it but hope to soon.  Good luck!

Comment: Sounds like a good approach but essentially the SSIS is still a stand alone component, executing directly against the target db and triggering from sql agent. I was wondering if i any advantages of 'wrapping' the ssis in the RESTful WS was worth it. It would mean consumers of data could trigger the ssis calls through the ws. I think i will leave it as a stand alone mechanism to refresh the data and have the ws remain exclusively for retrieving that data for the various consuming components eg the UI. thx for the suggestions, i like your caching logic.

Comment: Since this thread i have hit other issues with WCF so switch to WebAPI.  Regarding your question here though... I got the local cache working (using all c# code for POC) and it works great.  I am not holding for a time just checking last updated date from source, then handle the net changes if required per call.  Hugely reduces my web service calls.  Will switch this to call SSIS soon :)

Answer (score 1):

Personally i think its a bad idea to join the layers together.  You say adding the direct oracle logic would enhance the security - who will benefit here?  I suspect it would be easier to administer, having an additional security layer means you could add further security controls if necessary that the source/host system doesn't allow.  What if suddenly you are required to talk to SQL Server not oracle?  The RESTful service shouldn't care.

I host a lot of my services on a DMZ.  I am not allowed to open port 1521 from the DMZ through to the internal network for a whole host of reasons - therefore i have to go via an intermediate solution.

As far as simplifying the whole solution, you also have the issue that if you get a request for a similar call to similar data you will have to replicate the RESTful service and modify - obviously lots of code repeating in there.  Suddenly not so simple!

[Separation of concerns](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Separation_of_concerns) should be a priority.

Comment: Thx dom, i will take a look at the link